# How to show more decimals in a Chart.js chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-chartjs

I have this chart, and the real value of the price is like `0.0000571134`. The react-chartjs-2 only shows value to 3 decimals but I want the entire value to show or at least 8 decimals. I tried some settings in the datasets like `stepSize` but none of them worked.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';

import {Col, Row, Typography} from 'antd';

const {Title } = Typography;

const LineChart = ({coinHistory, currentPrice, coinName}) => {

    const coinPrice = [];
    const coinTimestamp = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < coinHistory?.data?.history?.length; i += 1) {
        coinPrice.push(coinHistory?.data?.history[i].price);
        coinTimestamp.push(new Date(coinHistory?.data?.history[i].timestamp).toLocaleDateString());
      }


      const data = {
        labels: coinTimestamp,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Price In USD',
            data: coinPrice,
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#0071bd',
            borderColor: '#0071bd',
          },
        ],
      };
      const options = {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [
            {
              ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true,
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      };
    

    return (
        <>
        <Row className="chart-header">
            <Title level={2} className="chart-title">{coinName} Price Chart</Title>
            <Col className="price-container">
                <Title level={5} className="price-change">Change: {coinHistory?.data?.change}%</Title>
                <Title level={5} className="current-price">Current {coinName} Price: $ {currentPrice}</Title>                
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Line data={data} options={options} />
        </>
    )
}

export default LineChart
```

coinHistory log:

> {"status":"success","data":{"change":147.09,"history":[{"price":"0.0000283221","timestamp":1634756400000},{"price":"0.0000282727","timestamp":1634760000000},

coinPrice log:

> "0.0000283221" "0.0000282727" "0.0000282314"

Answer (score 1):

Is working for me without any special treatment:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line', 
    data: {
        labels: ["Jun 2016", "Jul 2016", "Aug 2016", "Sep 2016", "Oct 2016", "Nov 2016", "Dec 2016", "Jan 2017", "Feb 2017", "Mar 2017", "Apr 2017", "May 2017"],
    datasets: [{
            label: 'Price In USD',
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: '#0071bd',
            borderColor: '#0071bd',
            data: [26.4231435453, 39.8231435453, 66.8231435453, 66.4231435453, 40.6231435453, 55.2231435453, 77.4231435453, 69.8231435453, 57.8231435453, 76, 110.8, 142.6],
        }]
    }
});
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Charts.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart">
        <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Make sure your `yValue` is of type decimal and you are not using `round`.

**EDIT 2:**

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-line-chart-example-forked-elv3v?file=/src/App.js) is literally your code forked (just input is copied from your code). It just seem like `LineChart`  component is not the problem. You should try to see if there is any config done anywhere in your app (for *"react-chartjs-2"*).

Or try to reproduce your problem somehow.

Comment: Thanks! I added my entire code snippet because it doesn't work for me. yValue is generated by react-chartjs from the datasets as I knew.

Comment: I also added a react example which works. And it has basically your options. Could you try to log JSON.stringify(coinPrice) and maybe JSON.stringify(coinHistory) as well?

Comment: I logged it  (which is in my question) and it seems okey.

Comment: I edited the sandbox again. But I don't see any way to help you without a reproduction because as mentioned: it seems like your problem is not laying inside `LineChart` component